# Angular ng-model dependent from other ng-model in forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-click, ng-options

I am trying to achieve a form with:

1 input radio ( 3 options )
2 select  ( 3 options )

Depend of the choice i mad in the select, the input[radio] should change
but also if i click a input[radio] the selects should show a initial value

[I made an easy example to understand what im trying here on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AK18bUUYXrIyTqbDhRag?p=preview)

-A client can choose a subscription, each subscription have a combo gift ( one gadget and one computer ) defined
there are 3 basic subscription: "bronze, silver and gold". If your choice match a combo plan defined, should change to some of them, and if the choice is a gadget-computer special combination, the plan should change to "platinum".

And if you click some plan the initial combo should be displayed

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="client">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ClientController as vm">
    <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
    <form>
      
      
      <label ng-repeat="subscription in vm.subscriptions">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.subscription" name="subscription" value="{{subscription.value}}" ng-click="vm.resetDependentFields()" required>
        {{subscription.name}}
      </label>
    
      <br>
      <br>

      <select name="gadgetList" ng-model="vm.gadget" ng-change="vm.planCombination()" ng-options="gadget for gadget in vm.subscriptions[vm.subscription].gadgetList">
      </select>


      <select name="computerList" ng-model="vm.computer" ng-change="vm.planCombination()" ng-options="computer for computer in vm.subscriptions[vm.subscription].computerList">
      </select>
      
      
    </form>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('client', [])
    .controller('ClientController', ClientController)

  function ClientController ( $log ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "NG Directives for forms"
    // Form initial value
    vm.planCombination = planCombination;
    vm.subscription    = 0;
  
    vm.subscriptions = [
      {
        name          : "bronze",
        value         : 0,
        initGadget    : "iPod",
        initComputer  : "MacBook Air",
        gadgetList    : ["iPod"       , "AppleWatch"  , "AppleTV"],
        computerList  : ["MacBook Air" , "MacBook Pro" , "iMac"],
        combination   : [["iPod","MacBookAir"]]
      },
      {
        name          : "silver",
        value         : 1,
        initGadget    : "iPod",
        initComputer  : "MacBook Pro",
        gadgetList    : ["iPod"       , "AppleWatch"  , "AppleTV"],
        computerList  : ["MacBook Air" , "MacBook Pro" , "iMac"],
        combination   : [["iPod","MacBook Pro"]]
      },
      {
        name          : "gold",
        value         : 2,
        initGadget    : "AppleWatch",
        initComputer  : "iMac",
        gadgetList    : ["iPod"       , "AppleWatch"  , "AppleTV"],
        computerList  : ["MacBook Air" , "MacBook Pro" , "iMac"],
        combination   : [["AppleWatch","iMac"]]
      },
      {
        name          : "platinum",
        value         : 3,
        initGadget    : "iPod",
        initComputer  : "iMac",
        gadgetList    : ["iPod"       , "AppleWatch"  , "AppleTV"],
        computerList  : ["MacBook Air" , "MacBook Pro" , "iMac"],
        combination   : [
          ["iPod","iMac"],
          ["AppleWatch", "MacBook Air"],
          ["AppleWatch", "MacBook Pro"],
          ["AppleTV", "MacBook Air"],
          ["AppleTV", "MacBook Pro"],
          ["AppleTV", "iMac"]
        ]
      }
    ];

    vm.gadget          = vm.subscriptions[vm.subscription].initGadget;
    vm.computer        = vm.subscriptions[vm.subscription].initComputer;

    // -----


    function planCombination () {
      if ( vm.gadget == "iPod" && vm.computer == "MacBook Air" ) {
        vm.subscription = "0";
      }
      else if (  vm.gadget == "iPod" && vm.computer == "MacBook Pro" ) {
        vm.subscription = "1";
      }
      else if (  vm.gadget == "AppleWatch" && vm.computer == "iMac" ) {
        vm.subscription = "2";
      }
      else {
        vm.subscription = "3";
      }
      
    
    }


  } // End Controller
})();
```

I'm using Angular 1.5, with the vm syntax instead of $scope
And i'm trying to avoid ng-init and setup initial values on the controller, because that said the official doc.

And i was playing with the ng-change ( think could be a good way using with the switch properly, any suggestion ? maybe a better way ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can check error messages for plnkr with the dev tools in your browser (ctrl+alt+I), the message is "planCombination is not defined". You are setting that value in your controller, but it's unknown.

Comment: Oh i din't know i could see on the inspector, example working now, gonna try with the ng-change :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction with **ng-change**. Connect a function to ng-change like this

```
<... ng-change="someFunction()">
```

then in the function you set the **model** as desired.

```
$scope.someFunction = function() {
    if ($scope.selectBoxValue == certainValue) {
        $scope.radioButonValue = someValue;
    } else { ... }
}
```

If this is not detailed enough let me know, I can make a more specific example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, i made the perfect example on plunkr but for some reason, the html didn't take the controller, works in local on my machine :S 

The ng-change should be located in the select tag right ? (i mean, there is no other place where place it because the <option> doesn't exist yet, would be generated.

Comment: Yes, place the ng-change in the select tag, because you want to react if the selection changes. In the function you then check the value of the model.

Comment: ok but the option generate this:  value="string:iPod
In the change function, should i use if (vm.gadget == "iPod )   or (vm.gadget == "string:iPod" )
Maybe it's a silly question but i don't know why the value has that string: syntax, we'already know that it's a string...

Comment: Ok, the ng-changes works sweet with the select, but how can i use now the ng-change ( or some other directive ) when i change the input[radio], you know, if i click right in the subscription

Comment: You have to add another ng-change to the radio with a different function. Did you try that?

Comment: That probably works but i thought radio updates automatically the vm.subscription value, that seams to be too verbose right ? i mean another function that do the same as last one but in the opposite way :S

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve. What do you want to do when the radio is selected?

Comment: If i change the selects and matches the combination, the right input-radio would be selected. 

but i also want that if i click in the input radio, the  init values for the right subscription plan would be displayed ( initGadget and initComputer )

Comment: If you want to change the value of another model, you have no other choice. You could avoid the explicit function by doing something like: ng-change="vm.gadget = gadgetInitValue; vm.computer = computerInitValue". Otherwise you need an init function that does it and call ng-change="init()"

Comment: Hey, if the solution helped you, it would be nice to mark the question as correct. If you still have problems, let me know.

Comment: Yeah i know, thanks for all.
I was checking the example and updating it first. Works perfect, but seems a little verbose, maybe someone can help to refactor this but the achievements its done ;)